# Angular: How to animate just changed items in a continuously read & overwritten list

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have a simple list with animated items (:enter & :leave animations) in my template:

```
@itemAnimation *ngFor="let item of list;
```

And an "ADD" button, which opens a form as a modal dialog, and user can add new items to the list.

After user clicks "SAVE" on modal, the model will be closed. After that, in order to always show the most current data (i.e. in a multi-tab case), we load all the items from backend again, and we set the list again:

```
 this.list = ....
```

In this case all the items will be animated again, and not just the new one (or the changed ones), since Angular thinks they are all new items. How can i animate just the new & changed items?

I know i can look for a change in my list, remove and re-add the changed ones in list manually. But i am looking for a simpler way (maybe angular built-in), which automatically detects and does not replace the old items.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the trackBy Function in tandem with *ngFor.
Per Docs: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngfor-with-trackby

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find the diff between `this.list` and a new list from BE. Then make `this.list.push(item)`.

Comment: yes this is an option.. i would like to see if there is any angular way of doing it automatically ..

Comment: I don't think Angular will track whether there's a diff automatically. When you do `this.list = [...]` it's basically setting new reference into the variable to the new Array. It is something you should handle yourself. Also, I don't think you even need to reload everything from the backend. If the model is a match, it's not necessary to make a new call.

Comment: the data can always be edited from others (i.e. Admins). So we should always load the new list with any action.

Comment: @VitaliiChmovzh sure it can -> change detection operations

Comment: @iLuvLogix It will not try to compare 2 arrays in case you set it directly, it will blatantly rerender the whole list, which happens in that case. That's why all animation been triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved this very problem in an app I am writing. It all boils down to the mutability of your data structures.

I won't go in to too much detail and give you the short answer... the angular animations directives will **NOT** work as you want with immutable arrays. You have to mutate existing arrays of items rather than pass in a fresh reference to a new array when updating your data.

To achieve this at a component level, the cleanest way (in my opinion) is to keep your component communication immutable (use observables with the async pipe to pass fresh state down-stream), but when it actually comes to the presentational component you must mutate an existing collection and maintain it **ALONGSIDE** your immutable inputs... like this:

`@Input() collection: any[]` <-- immutable input

`mutableCollection: any[]` <-- mutable collection

In practise this means writing some gross mutative functions, being careful to use only mutating array methods.

[Here is a great article highlighting mutative vs non-mutating array methods](https://lorenstewart.me/2017/01/22/javascript-array-methods-mutating-vs-non-mutating/)

If this doesn't make sense I can show you some code highlighting the differences between mutably & immutably updating an array, just throw a comment here.